# Google Drive access without user login

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am making an app for the iPhone were all the users have access to the same google drive folder for uploading files. This google drive account is managed by the company and not by the users. There for I want to skip the google login form and just give the user access. Ideal the user does not even know he/she is using google drive.

I looked at the drEdit example and looked at oauth documentation. Is it possible to use one refresh_token for all the users to grand access? So I login once, grand access, somehow store the refresh_token and hard code that in the app for future use, so that all the users use that refresh_token for access. Or are there better ideas to do this?

Kind regards,

Stijn

Comment: There may be efficient solution to this.One possibility is to have a web service that provides the secure information(refresh token or any other info that is needed to log in to service). Every time application can access from the web service. Once retrieved information can also be stored in user keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Thought there was a similar question to this, but can't find the one I'm looking for. Short answer is you need to be very careful how you do this. Embedding the refresh token in your app like that is inviting abuse, particularly if it is authorized for write access. Once a clever user or attacker finds that value, they can use that token to call the API however they want. If authorized for the full drive scope, that means that can also maliciously modify or delete files, secretly store their own content, etc...

If you really need to have anonymous or shared access to content stored in Drive, you're better off proxying requests through your own servers so you can control the interaction with Drive.